# Create schema in Heroku Postgresql DB

Tags: sql, postgresql, heroku

I'm trying to create a schema in heroku DB. I tried using `heroku pg:psql --app app_name DATABASE < schema.sql`

schema.sql:

```
CREATE SCHEMA schema_name AUTHORIZATION user_name;
```

But my program still says that schema_name doesn't exist. Maybe I'm missing something

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found the problem! I was using Windows console but `heroku pg:psql --app app_name DATABASE < schema.sql` command didn't work here. I used MINGWN32 console and the following command: `cat schema.sql | heroku pg:psql --app app_name` and everything worked!